# Search through second level data sets in an Algolia Index

Tags: javascript, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I have the following Algolia index imported from firebase database and I can search through everything on Algolia dashboard [image]

but when in the search box on my website I can't search through "inventory".
these are some of my codes

```
   //configure algolia
 var index = algolia.initIndex('Businesses');

  var businessRef = database.ref("/Businesses");


   businessRef.on('child_added', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);
   businessRef.on('child_changed', addOrUpdateIndexRecord);
   businessRef.on('child_removed', deleteIndexRecord);
```

index settings

```
      index.setSettings({
    searchableAttributes: [
      'NSN',
      'PartNumber',
      'ProductDescription',
      'ProductName',
      'Inventory',
    ],
    customRanking: ['desc(NSN)'],

    function(err, content) {
      console.log(content);
    }

  })
```

client

```
    client.initIndex('Inventory').setSettings({
      "searchableAttributes": [
        'NSN',
      'PartNumber',
      'ProductDescription',
      'ProductName',
      'Inventory'
      ],
      customRanking: [
        'desc(NSN)'
      ],
      function(err, content) {
          console.log(content);
        }
    });
```

front end

```
    <script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
              <div class="hit">

                <div class="hit-content">
                <h2 class="hit-name">  {{{_highlightResult.NSN.value}}}</h2>
                  <p class="hit-description">{{{_highlightResult.ProductName.value}}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </script>
```

What I want to do is to search through only inventory from the search box. How can I do this ?

Comment: any code you can show?

Comment: I've added some of the code?

Answer (score 1):

can you also provide your search query parameters and front-end client options?

Did you add `inventory` attribute to the `searchableAttributes` settings?

Comment: thanks! Can you add the front-end client options? Or maybe provide a live example if you can. I want to see the request parameters that you send.

Comment: Also can you grant support access? it will be easier to help you that way https://www.algolia.com/users/edit#?tab=access-control

Comment: what's your APP_ID?

Comment: this is it 2NLAZPOWMU

Comment: Hey Ola it seems that you are applying settings on one index (Inventory) but you are searching in another index (Business). Plus looking at your index, it seems that you didn't set any settings at all in the Inventory index.

Comment: Thank you Raphi for your time. I tried having the setting on Business but could not search the Inventory node so I decided to create a separate index for inventory and then search through that but still no luck. I wanted to do the setting but I could not set it to my desired attribute. I have deleted Inventory now, i just want to focus on businesses. How can I search through these attributes in Businesses.                                                     'NSN',
      'PartNumber',
      'ProductDescription',
      'ProductName',